# default_content import error field content_translation_source is unknown

Tags: blocks, importing-exporting

I've exported a custom block content using default content module, when trying to import, I'm getting error

```
[ERROR] Field content_translation_source is unknown.
```

I've all 4 language modules enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Content translation module was enabled but content translation was not enabled for custom block. Enabling it fixed the error.